java.io.NotSerializableException: org.primefaces.model.file.UploadedFileWrapper
Esto tratando de cargar un archivo con <p:fileUpload> de primefaces 11.0 y obtener su nombre pero estoy obteniendo la siguiente excepción:
15:25:42,463 ERROR [mx.myapp.pau.mb.MBAdjuntarMaterialConsulta] (default task-1) File 
name: RA00544-23.mp3
15:25:42,638 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception 
handling request to /pau/app/modulos/adjuntar_materiales/consulta: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)

Caused by: org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.<init>(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:75)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.createSnapshot(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:70)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.snapshot(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:75)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.putFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:126)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:170)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:254)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:55)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
... 132 more

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.primefaces.model.file.UploadedFileWrapper
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.engmyapp.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.writeExternal(FlowExecutionImpl.java:311)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1460)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.serialize(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:173)
at mx.myapp.spring:5.1.8//org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.<init>(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:70)
... 141 more

Mi clase esta serializada y no estoy usando objetos adicionales, así que entiendo que el error lo marca en la clase UploadedFileWrapper pero al ser una clase de una biblioteca no tengo manera de serializarla.
Alguna idea para resolver este error?
Agrego mi pedacito de código que lanza la excepción
public void agregaArchivo(FileUploadEvent e) {
    String nombre = e.getFile().getFileName();
    log.error("Nombre archivo: " + nombre);
}


¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Problemas con Serializacion aplicacion Cliente-Servidor
